# Как добавить проверку через метод assertEquals() или assertTrue(), после цикла? Selenide

Tags: java, selenium, junit, selenide

Не понимаю, как добавить проверку с помощью методов assertEquals() или assertTrue(). Как это сделать правильно в данном случае? Это касается авто теста в Selenide (Selenium + JUnit)
Пробовал через метод, но не получается что-то. Зеленый еще...
Ниже код под который хочу написать проверку. На UI просто отображается динамический текст и хочется проверить, что он отображается и нету других багов.

```
public class AnalyticsPage {
@Step("бла бла")
public static void checkingQuantity() {
    Number actual ;
    int actualNumber = $$x("//span[@class='label-value']").size();
    for (int i=0; i<actualNumber; i++) {
        String actualText = $$x("//span[@class='label-value']").get(i).text();
        System.out.println(actualText);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Тут надо сначала чутка попрактиковаться просто с Java.
Для начала, переменная actual у вас объявлена, но не используется. IDEA её подсвечивает - обращайте внимание на её подсказки.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что касается тесты, лучше использовать встроенные селенидовские проверки, примерно так:

```
$$x("//span[@class='label-value']").shouldHave(size(4));

$$x("//span[@class='label-value']").shouldHave(texts("foo", "bar", "zzz", "xxx""));
```

Comment: спасибо, но я хотел бы знать именно про те два методы из заголовка.